# After Parrot os update Busybox v1.22.1 initramfs error

Tags: parrotsec

I was upgrading and updating my Parrot os 3.2 yesterday. After the restart I get Busybox v1.22.1 initramfs error in my screen:

[image]

Now I have read some where that I must use a live usb so I did that and type the following command:

```
┌─[user@parrot]─[~]
└──╼ $ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 7.5 GiB, 8015314944 bytes, 15654912 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x4ef96f1d

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         64 7253183 7253120   3.5G 17 Hidden HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda2       7253184 7489791  236608 115.5M  1 FAT12


Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x550a3000

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1               63      80324      80262  39.2M de Dell Utility
/dev/sdb2  *         81920   24686591   24604672  11.8G 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sdb3         24686592 1851119615 1826433024 870.9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb4       1851121662 1953523711  102402050  48.8G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       1936982016 1953523711   16541696   7.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb6       1851121664 1860887288    9765625   4.7G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb7       1860888576 1936973823   76085248  36.3G 83 Linux

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/loop0: 3.2 GiB, 3394400256 bytes, 6629688 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
┌─[user@parrot]─[~]
└──╼ $
```

But I am stuck here as you can see.

This is my Parrot os that I use to use, but it doesn't boot normal any more after the update.

```
/dev/sdb7 1860888576 1936973823 76085248 36.3G 83 Linux
```

What to do next?

Comment: It looks like some version of a Microsoft operating system is also installed on your system.  Which version is it and are you currently using it?  When you first installed Parrot, did you select the "Standard Installer" option?  What mount points and partitions did you configure during the initial install?  Did you at any time create a separate partition for "/root"?  It looks kind of like the boot loader thinks "/root" is your system root partition.  Are you using grub?  Sorry for so many questions but any answers could help lead you or someone else to a solution.

Comment: Hello first of all thanks for takin time to read my quistion   .

Comment: The version of the MS os is windows 7. but that is workig fine if i duel boot

Comment: When i installed Parrot i used duel boot option on my hard drive.

Comment: I was using parrot for months without any problems  until I did a system updgrade & update. I was using Parrot os 3.2 and now there is another version 3.4 .Thats why I was trying to update,but when i restart my computer,the problem began. And yes I am using grub loader. I know i can fix this because others had the same problem to but solved it without reinstall Parrot os again. I

Comment: Here is someone who had the same problem and solved it.                        https://youtu.be/91TaW1LCRkM

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand your video link. If it was related to fixing your partition alignment warnings, that is likely not the problem.  For what it's worth, which isn't much I'm afraid, I was able to install the latest version of Parrot from scratch in a KVM virtual machine.  I might be off base, but that image of your system trying to mount /dev/sda7 on /root, /dev on /root/dev, etc. just seems bizarre. Was there _anything_ unusual about the upgrade process?  I'll think about this some more.  Oh, and the overall readability here is degraded when you have many 1-line posts ;-)

Comment: Yeah i can't understand either because its spanish,the only thing I know he had the same problem,anyway I dident see anything unusual.The only thing I am going to try is keep on reading and searching to try and solve this case. I am going to type in google  Busybox v1.22.1 initramfs error, and just search for answers for hours :) Thanks for the help and suggestions.

Comment: Actually, I would start with the initramfs.  Look up how to rebuild it from your live cd.  If I knew how to do that in Debian I'd walk you through it. If someone else knows how off the top of their head and they thinks it's worth trying they might post.  It shouldn't be that hard though, I'd just go to the Debian wiki and dig!

Comment: mmmm you gave me a good idea,I am going to do some research thanks and work it out.If the problem is solved ill let you know.

Comment: this is the exact problem what i have. http://dcageek.blogspot.nl/2013/02/ubuntu-initramfs-error-during-boot.html

Comment: Yep, that looks like your problem and I think you'll resolve it soon.  Remember that you can, and in fact are encouraged to, answer your own question if you find the solution.  That will help others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
initramfs: fsck /dev/sda1
```

Let the machine  do Everything an then type exit

```
initramfs: exit
```

Comment: Runing `fsck` on `/dev/sdb7` should solve the problem